# neo4j data model for user and role

Tags: database, neo4j

I want to modal a use-case in neo4j.

UseCase :

User

Role

Department

Permission

Here a user can have multiple roles and user can be associated with multiple departments through multiple roles.

Ex:

User A is connected with Department X with role role A,role B and same user is connected to department y with role A and role c,further each role will have set of permissions.

Suggest neo4j data-model.

Answer (score 3):

http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/examples-user-roles-in-graphs.html and http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/examples-acl-structures-in-graphs.html both provide a very good reference which you can consult to build up your model

Comment: This is simple case where only user and roles are modelled,i want department,permissions also connected.

Comment: You probably need a hyperedge http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/cypher-cookbook-hyperedges.html

Comment: Thanks,is hyperedge something special,as in given example,they have just introduced an additional node and if you know, does spring-data-neo4j(SDN) support this hyperedge.

Comment: Please see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#tutorial_domain